# How do I run a script/command on suspend?

Tags: suspend, docky, gnome-do

I'm running Ubuntu 10.04 and the gnome-do docky applet. For some reason every so often (sometimes after one, sometimes after several suspends) when I wake up from a suspend (I'm on a laptop, so every time I close the screen in-between my classes) gnome-do starts devouring the CPU. Trying to use the quit button on gnome-do doesn't work, I have to kill -1 the process.

Apparently it's been a problem for several people as there is at least one [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/do/+bug/450852). According to the bug report it's been fixed, but the release hasn't been pushed into the PPA. So my idea was to have the suspend script kill gnome-do automagically and then I'd just have to start it up again when I wake up (or set that in a wakeup script). Unfortunately my google-fu seems to fail me - I've found plenty of info about shutdown and logout, but nothing on suspend.

Any pointers? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you can put a shell script in `/etc/pm/sleep.d/` which will be run on suspend/hibernate/resume/thaw. See the `pm-suspend` manpage for more information.

I'd also recommend trying gnome-do from trunk (`bzr branch lp:do`) and seeing if this fixes it. If so, we can look at getting a targetted fix in as an SRU.

Comment: I finally got around to installing from source. It told me that docky was now a standalone program?

Comment: Right. I don't think this was a problem with the docky theme specifically though, so unless you plan on no longer using Do then please continue to try from source.

Answer (score 1):

You could `kill -s STOP <pid>` before and `kill -s CONT <pid>` after. This will suspend and then resume the process giving absolutely no CPU cycles while the computer is starting to go to sleep and when it's waking up. It's a bit of a stretch but maybe it will work.

Combine it with Iain Lane's `/etc/pm/sleep.d/` idea and you got a completely automated solution.

Answer (score 0):

Put a script in `/etc/pm/sleep.d/`. The file name should start with an ordering number, 00-49 for user scripts, and you can differ between suspend and wakeup by an argument that will be passed to the script (for more details on both, see `man pm-suspend`).

When killing it, I suggest doing

```
(killall -1 gnome-do; exit 0)
```

in the script. Otherwise, if you try to suspend, and process `gnome-do` isn't running, the `killall` will exit with exit code 1, which will cancel the entire suspend. The above will run `killall` in a sub-shell that will exit with 0.

If you're having problems, check `/var/log/pm-suspend.log` that will log the attempt to run your script and possible problems.

Answer (score 0):

The key is to run docky process in background with & command. Otherwise some other problems occur.

You can find full solution this page:
http://www.linux-compatible.com/tutorial/docky-closes-after-waking-suspend-ubuntu